# PHP: json_encode format

Tags: php, json

I have a table with a list of businesses. Each row has details such as the business name, ID, area,number just to mention a few.

I am querying the mysql database and currently i'm only retrieving the business name and ID.
I am then using the json_encode function to get an output like: `{"BusinessA":"business_A_ID","BusinessB":"business_B_ID"}`

I would like to be able to retrieve all of the business details and use the json encode function to get an output like:

```
[
    {
        "businessName": "BusinessA",
        "businessID": "business_A_ID"
    },
    {
        "businessName": "BusinessB",
        "businessID": "businees_B_ID"
    }
]
```

Here is the current code i'm using:

```
$businessRow = array();
        $businessResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM businessTable");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($businessResult)) {
            $businessRow[$row['businessName']] = $row['businessID'];
            }
            $result = json_encode($businessRow);
            echo $result;
```

So my question is what do I need to change this line to  :

```
$businessRow[$row['businessName']] = $row['businessID'];
```

in order to get the above JSON output?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem what doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried json_encode($businessResult);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your script like this:

```
$businessRow[] = array(
    'businessName' => $row['businessName'],
    'businessID'   => $row['businessID']
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want:

```
$rows = array();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT businessName, businessID FROM businessTable");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

`$row` will already be of the form `array('businessName' => '...', 'businessID' => '...')`, so all you have to do is to add it to your final array and encode it.